# Wordpress functions do not work via Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm creating a plugin for Wordpress with an audio recorder. When you click a button I need to call a function from within my plugin to send an email with this audio.

I dont know how to use the `do_action()` for this case. I'm trying via AJAX, however when I do the *POST* request to the main PHP file from my plugin, the Wordpress functions (`wp_mail()`) are not working which I'm using to send the email.

Does anyone know if this is normal behavior of Wordpress? How can I implement this e-mail sender with the audio?

Answer (score 0):

First you need use right AJAX hooks see follow example how to `do_action`:

```
// for logged users only
add_action( 'wp_ajax_add_foobar', 'prefix_ajax_add_foobar' );
// for public site
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_add_foobar', 'prefix_ajax_add_foobar' );

function prefix_ajax_add_foobar() {
    // Handle request then generate response using WP_Ajax_Response
}
```

See [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)) how to write ajax function.

Function `wp_mail` should working as you expect, but maybe you can have problems with local SMTP or email service. Try use some free SMTPs with [SMTP plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/).